# How to trim field value in Paginated Report Power BI

Tags: powerbi, expression, powerbi-paginated-reports

I would like help with adding an expression for trimming a field value in a paginated report. The field consists of a first name, last name and number inside of it. I would only like to show the first and last name, but I am not sure how to . I have been trying to use LEN, LEFT, and RIGHT, but I'm not sure how to use it right. Below is an example of a value

"Sarah Lipton 4568875312"  < This would be displayed when selecting the field name "Personnel".

"Sarah Lipton"  < I would like it to display as this.

All of the phone numbers are the same length of 10 characters.

Please help me add an expression to trim the field content.

I tried =Left(Fields!Personnel.Value, Len(Fields!Personnel.Value) - InStr(Fields!Personnel.Value, "4"))

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of right and replace. I use right function to get the phone number and replaced that number with a space in the original field. Field value name I used is, "column" substitute the relevant field name, and you are good to go.

```
=Replace(Fields!column.Value,Right(Fields!column.Value,11),"")
```

[image]